# IE8 to show smaller font when printing, how?

Tags: asp.net, css, printing, internet-explorer-8

So i have the identical page and trying to print with IE8 and IE9.  In IE9 it seems to shrink the page when printing to show entire page, while in IE8 some of the divs that are absolute values are off the screen.

Problem is that font size when printing in IE8 is bigger than when printing with IE9.  How can I make sure that the font size is smaller, just like in IE9.

Comment: How are you declaring your font sizes?

Comment: Asside from that, I am wondering why is the print shrinking in IE9 and not in IE8? Is there a way to force this?  Font sizes are specifieed per element, so I dont think I need to change each element in order to get this working in IE8... At least I hope not..

Comment: It depends on how you declared your font sizes.

Comment: Mostly like font-size: 8px; etc... for each element.

Comment: You can use a print stylesheet - if you specify a width in pixels for the body (try 700px) then IE8 may behave a little better, but the print engines in browsers vary greatly. The only way to guarantee print size across them all is to generate a PDF on the server and send it to the user to print.

Comment: Does IE know what the DPI of your screen is?

Comment: Right now I have somrthing like this...                                       @media print 
{
    marquee { -moz-binding: none; }
    body{ overflow: visible !important;
}

Comment: Mr Lister, how would I find that out...

Comment: Is there a way to write in CSS to make the IE8 to Shrink to Fit?